# Recreate Acces VBA function in SQL or C# and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, vba, ms-access

So, I have an Access application which has a function like such;

```
Function PutNum() As Boolean
On Error GoTo Err_PutNum
Dim t_ct As Integer, rst As ADODB.Recordset, Str As String
 
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
 
rst.Open "qrySelectUpdatePrior", CurrentProject.Connection, _
adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTableDirect
 
t_ct = 49
With rst
     Str = .Fields("ssn")
     Do While Not .EOF
        If Str = .Fields("ssn") Then
            t_ct = t_ct + 1
            .Fields("PRIOR") = "0" & t_ct
        
        Else
            t_ct = 50
            .Fields("PRIOR") = "0" & t_ct
            Str = .Fields("ssn")
        End If
        .MoveNext
     Loop
    .Close
End With
Set rst = Nothing
PutNum = True
 
Exit_PutNum:
   
    Exit Function
Err_PutNum:
    MsgBox Error$
    PutNum = False
    Resume Exit_PutNum
 
End Function
```

The query for the record set looks like this;

```
SELECT DRS_FILE.SSN, DRS_FILE.PRIOR
FROM DRS_FILE
ORDER BY DRS_FILE.SSN, DRS_FILE.P1, DRS_FILE.P2;
```

The goal of this function is to grab a record set analyze the Social Security number to determine how many times a Social Security Number shows up in a record set and then update the record set field “PRIOR” with the results. The sequence is as follows;

1.       The First time a Social Security Number is identified  the “PRIOR” Field  gets updated with 050

2.       The Second Time a Social Security Number is identified the “PRIOR” Field gets updated with 051

3.       The Third Time a Social Security Number is identified the “PRIOR” Field gets updated with 052

4.       Etc…

As you can see there is a pattern. I am now tasked with recreating this functionality but I didn’t know what the best option was in regards to if I should complete this task in SQL Server only (stored procedures and functions) or if I should use C# in conjunction with SQL Server to complete this task. Record sets will total well over 100 Thousands records and I am afraid of processing so many records on the application side as passing the data back and forth between the front end of the application and SQL server seems very taxing to me but I could be wrong. My goal is to not risk performance.

If anyone has any ideas on how to accomplish this task please share as I have been racking my brain for some time. If you have any sample code to share that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to port your code to .NET/C# or .NET/VB, it should be fairly easy to recreate the code line by line, since you will probably still use ADO. I have a pure MS Access SQL solution here. But it requires creating table temporarily:

step 1. make a query that calculates PRIOR values and inserts them into a new table: [New_Prior_Tbl]

```
SELECT * INTO New_Prior_Tbl
FROM (SELECT 
      OuterTbl.ID AS LookUpKey, 
      "0" & 49 +(SELECT count(*) FROM DRS_FILE AS InnerTbl WHERE OuterTbl.ID >= InnerTbl.ID AND OuterTbl.SSN = InnerTbl.SSN  ) AS PRIOR 
     FROM DRS_FILE AS OuterTbl 
     ORDER BY OuterTbl.SSN, OuterTbl.P1, OuterTbl.P2) 
AS Temp;
```

step 2. Update the PRIOR field in main table:

```
UPDATE DRS_FILE AS DestTbl 
INNER JOIN New_Prior_Tbl AS SrcTbl 
ON DestTbl.ID = SrcTbl.LookUpKey 
SET DestTbl.PRIOR = SrcTbl.PRIOR;
```

step 3. drop temporary table

```
DROP TABLE New_Prior_Tbl;
```

Comment: I have been wondering if I should complete this task in SQL as a stored procedure as I can use your code. What do you think?

Comment: I don't know your company well enough point to one solution over the other. But i think you should consider things like performance, change requirements, and stability. In theory the solution i wrote shouldn't be the most efficient one in a large table. If you are moving to .net/C# you will have better query tools at you disposal (Linq, ADO), and C# code is easier to maintain/update in (my opinion). C# is also indifferent of which DB you use (Entity Framework), so you would be able to  switch DB at later time. Stored procedures cannot be moved to different DB easly. What about ETL like SSIS?